# How do I order objects, but also with certain attributes listed first?

Tags: ruby

I've got this

```
@requests = current_fan.handled_requests.order(:id).reverse_order
```

but I want to put requests with `new_response = true` listed first (at the top) (listed also in reverse order of their :id if possible, but not necessary)

```
 @requests = current_fan.handled_requests.order(:id).reverse_order.order(:new_response)
```

didn't work

```
@requests = current_fan.handled_requests.order(:id).reverse_order.prioritize(:new_response)
```

I made that one up

Comment: `order(id: :desc)` is the easy reverse way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple order criteria and order directions to `order` like this:

```
current_fan.handled_requests.order(new_response: :desc, id: :desc)
```

`new_response: :desc` will order records with `new_response == true` at the top and with `new_response == false` to the bottom. And when there are multiple records with the same `new_response`  value, then those records will be sorted with `id: :desc` by their `id` in descending order.